# How to get value from a JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json

I am a new of `JSON` and really I don't know how to get value from inner object.
Now I need to get the "Description" value from `JSON` object response.

**JSON Data:**

```
{"Fault":{"faultcode":"Client", "faultstring":"An exception has been raised as a result of client data.", "detail":{"Errors":{"ErrorDetail":{"Severity":"Hard", "PrimaryErrorCode":{"Code":"111285", "Description":"The postal code 95472 is invalid for FL United States."}}}}}}
```

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2ce7ac5f329bd18f06000788ba7946dc

**Expecting Result:**

The postal code 95472 is invalid for FL United States.

**Sample Code:**

```
       success    : function(response) 
        {                       
            //alert("response="+response);         
alert("Description="+Fault.detail.Errors.ErrorDetail.PrimaryErrorCode.Description);    
        }
```

Comment: In javascript: `var json = JSON.parse('{"Fault":{"faultcode":"Client", "faultstring":"An exception has been raised as a result of client data.", "detail":{"Errors":{"ErrorDetail":{"Severity":"Hard", "PrimaryErrorCode":{"Code":"111285", "Description":"The postal code 95472 is invalid for FL United States."}}}}}}');` then you can access it as `json.Fault.detail.Errors.ErrorDetail.PrimaryErrorCode.Description`

Comment: Thanks @alex-szabó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON string can be parsed using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method and use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to get the number from the string.

```js
var json = '{"Fault":{"faultcode":"Client", "faultstring":"An exception has been raised as a result of client data.", "detail":{"Errors":{"ErrorDetail":{"Severity":"Hard", "PrimaryErrorCode":{"Code":"111285", "Description":"The postal code 95472 is invalid for FL United States."}}}}}}'

console.log("Description=" + JSON.parse(json).Fault.detail.Errors.ErrorDetail.PrimaryErrorCode.Description.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

---

If you had a valid js object(may be already parsed) then there is no need to parse it again.

```js
var obj = {"Fault":{"faultcode":"Client", "faultstring":"An exception has been raised as a result of client data.", "detail":{"Errors":{"ErrorDetail":{"Severity":"Hard", "PrimaryErrorCode":{"Code":"111285", "Description":"The postal code 95472 is invalid for FL United States."}}}}}};

console.log("Description=" + obj.Fault.detail.Errors.ErrorDetail.PrimaryErrorCode.Description.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

Comment: @RamaLingam :  glad to help :)